# Android:android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 in

Tags: android, resources, runtime-error

i'm new to android and its my first attempt paymnet getway intigration with android app.I got the 'sdk' for android from atom's official site and correctly intigrate it, when I'm trying to call PayActivity.java from library MobilePaymentSDKOutput.jar which `androidsdk` given by atom payment getway . When i run the app in emulator it shows following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.lightwave.plwpay/com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk.PayActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2155)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1155)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:420)
        at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:557)
        at a.a(SourceFile:66)
        at j.onPreExecute(SourceFile:796)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:595)
        at com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk.PayActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:2215)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

here is the java code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView whichCard;
ImageButton payNow,cancel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this, ""+ Constants.whichCard, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        if (!Constants.whichCard.equals("")) {
            whichCard.setText(Constants.whichCard);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nullll", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}

    payNow= findViewById(R.id.payNow);
    cancel= findViewById(R.id.cancelPay);


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    payNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent newPayIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PayActivity.class);

            newPayIntent.putExtra("merchantId", "459");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("txnscamt", "0"); //Fixed. Must be �0�
            newPayIntent.putExtra("loginid", "459");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("password", "Test@123");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("prodid", "NSE");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("txncurr", "INR"); //Fixed. Must be �INR�
            newPayIntent.putExtra("clientcode", "001");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("custacc", "100000036900");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("amt", "50.000");//Should be 3 decimal number i.e 1.000
            newPayIntent.putExtra("txnid", "01");
            newPayIntent.putExtra("date", "25/08/2015 18:31:00");//Should be in same format
            newPayIntent.putExtra("bankid", "2019"); //Should be valid bank id

            //use below Production url only with Production "Library-MobilePaymentSDK", Located inside PROD folder
            //newPayIntent.putExtra("ru","https://payment.atomtech.in/mobilesdk/param"); //ru FOR Production

            //use below UAT url only with UAT "Library-MobilePaymentSDK", Located inside UAT folder
            newPayIntent.putExtra("ru", "https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/mobilesdk/param"); // FOR UAT (Testing)

            //Optinal Parameters
            newPayIntent.putExtra("customerName", "Sweta sap"); //Only for Name
            newPayIntent.putExtra("customerEmailID", "sap.sweta@atomtech.in");//Only for Email ID
            newPayIntent.putExtra("customerMobileNo", "9876043210");//Only for Mobile Number
            newPayIntent.putExtra("billingAddress", "Mumbai");//Only for Address
            newPayIntent.putExtra("optionalUdf9", "OPTIONAL DATA 1");// Can pass any data

            startActivityForResult(newPayIntent, 1);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            String message = data.getStringExtra("status");
            String[] resKey = data.getStringArrayExtra("responseKeyArray");
            String[] resValue = data.getStringArrayExtra("responseValueArray");

            if(resKey!=null && resValue!=null)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<resKey.length; i++)
                    System.out.println("  "+i+" resKey : "+resKey[i]+" resValue : "+resValue[i]);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

}
```

}

Kindly guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Check the dependancy you are using, there is issue in com.atom.mobilepaymentsdk.PayActivity means in the library I guess. Check if you are using latest version or not.

Comment: no,its not latest version , actual i'm using android-Version 28  and the library has android-Version 24.

Comment: I am talking about the version of atom sdk you are using not supported android version.

Comment: sorry to wrong information , yes it is updated version of atom sdk

Comment: i got the solution , thank you very much to helping me

Comment: What was the issue? if my comment helped you pls upvote.

Comment: actually, i forget to attach layout file which is the used in PayActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `PayActivity` is there and there is no problem, I suggest you try with clearing the cache (`Build -> Clean Project or File -> Invalidat Caches/Restart ...`). You can even check if it is normal in the packaged `apk`.

Comment: hello @xin.ye , yes clean the project but still there is same problem

Comment: PayActivity.java in a jar file, so i don't know is there any problem or not

Comment: em, you can see the source code in the jar package.